# Can I wrap paths in SVG with a transparent rectangular element? I want to make an entire SVG image into a clickable link

Tags: svg

I basically have an SVG logo, with lots of transparent space, and I want to link the whole thing to another page. If it were an alpha PNG I'd just wrap the whole thing in an <a> and be done with it, but when I wrap all of the <paths> none of the transparent areas are linked.

```
<svg width="100px" height="52px" enable-background="new 0 0 750.72 391.873">
<a xlink:href="http://www.mysite.com" id="anchor">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="..."/>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="..."/>
</a>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an invisible rect (visibility="hidden") that fills the viewport and then set pointer-events="all" on it to capture all of the mouse clicks.

Alternatively if you took the link out of the SVG and made it a standalone file you could include it via the `<img>` tag into wherever it should go and then wrap the `<img>` tag with an `<a>` tag.

Comment: visibility="hidden" makes areas unclickable. Use a low opacity instead.

Comment: @MortezaE feel free to write your own answer, but note that I already cover clickability via pointer-events in the first paragraph of my answer.